# Transform an excel table row with multiple entries into unique rows with relevant column info

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have an excel table like this.
[image]

I am seeking to convert it into something like this.

[image]

I have tried using powerquery to automate this but I am nowhere close to what I want it to be. Does any of you have any suggestions how I can get it done? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In powerquery, right click the Date column and choose unpivot other columns

You can then edit the code from

```
= Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"Column1"}, "Attribute", "Value")
```

to

```
= Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"Column1"}, "Item", "Amount")
```

to change column titles

Answer (score 1):

Select the item columns and then unpivot the data ...

**Source Data**

[image: Unpivot]

**Result**

[image: Result]